# How to get all different values(or keys) in a hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, key

I have a little problem with some hashes.

if i have a hash containing, John,John,John,Bob,Bob,Paul - is there then a function that can return just:

John, Bob, Paul.

In other words i want to get all different values(or keys if value is not possible) - but only once :).

I hope u understand my question, thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this may help you:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw{ uniq };

my %hash = ( a => 'Paul', b => 'Paul', c => 'Peter' );
my @uniq_names = uniq values %hash;
print "@uniq_names\n";
```

Keys are uniq always.

Comment: The button can only be pressed after a certain timelimit :p

Answer (score 3):

TIMTOWTDI:

```
my @unique = keys { reverse %hash };
```

Note the performance caveat with [`reverse`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) though:

---

> This operator is also handy for inverting a hash, although there are
>   some caveats. If a value is duplicated in the original hash, only one
>   of those can be represented as a key in the inverted hash. Also, this
>   has to unwind one hash and build a whole new one, which may take some
>   time on a large hash, such as from a DBM file.
>
> ```
> %by_name = reverse %by_address;  # Invert the hash
> ```

Comment: I think you need `keys { reverse %hash }` for `keys` to work properly.

Comment: @TLP : Right you are. Omitting the curlies results in an unpleasant message: `Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref`

Answer (score 2):

De-duping is easily (and idiomatically) done by using a hash:

```
my @uniq = keys { map { $_ => 1 } values %hash };
```

A simple enough approach that does not require installing modules. Since hash keys must be unique, any list of strings become automatically de-duped when used as keys in the same hash.

Note the use of curly braces forming an anonymous hash `{ ... }` around the `map` statement. That is required for `keys`.

Note also that `values %hash` can be any list of strings, such as one or more arrays, subroutine calls and whatnot.

Comment: If installing modules is not an option, emulating `uniq` is easy enough: `sub uniq { my %seen; grep { ! $seen{$_} } @_ }` .

Comment: @Zaid That sub does not dedupe for me, it just returns all the values. If you make it `! $seen{$_}++` it works.

Comment: I don't know what happened to the `++`, sorry about that :)

Comment: @Zaid You're out of shape, after such long absence, perhaps. ;)